# Is there an alternate to java.lang.String.format() in java to use generic placeholder

Tags: java, string-formatting

slf4j Logger has a formatter syntax that is clean. ( Use of curly braces )

```
org.slf4j.Logger.error("Invalid value1={} for value2={}", value1, value1)
```

Is the below method has a similar alternative? I want a generic ({}) instead of type-specific place-holder.

```
String.format("Invalid value1=%d for value2=%d", value1, value1)
```

Comment: You can use `%s` in `.format`. That's not type specific.

Comment: @khelwood how it isn't type specific, when it takes string representations for the passed objects?

Comment: @dbl and what do you think `{}` does?

Comment: I don't think anything, rather I do check the docs. The claim above is incorrect :) Even though it the most appropriate substitution in that case.
`'s', 'S' general If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". If arg implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked. Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking arg.toString().`

Comment: You're building a message. Taking a string representation of the objects is exactly what you're trying to do. And it's what `{}` does in a logger.

Comment: Found this, but looking for a utility method from utility open source jars like guava or apache common .

`org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat ( "Invalid value1={} for value2={}", new Object[] { value1, value2 }).getMessage()`

Comment: @cyrilantony either check *khelwood* comment or *Mafor* answer. Like `String.format("Invalid value1=%s for value2=%s", value1, value2)` or `MessageFormat.format("Invalid value1={0} for value2={1}", value1, value2);`

Comment: Do you have an actual use case where `String.format` with `%s` won't do what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) with `%s`.

```
String.format("Invalid value1=%s for value2=%s", value1, value1)
```

`%s` works for all types, just as `{}` does in your logger. It converts any given argument to a string, which seems to be exactly your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) if you prefer, although you would need to specify argument numbers:

```java
MessageFormat.format("Invalid value1={0} for value2={1}", value1, value2);
```

Comment: The `%s` would be a better match in the context of the OP.